# MySQL Join two different columns in the same table twice in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have `announcements` table, where I store `announcements.catid` (category id).

Categories table `categories` are used to be nested with the use of `categories.pid`.

What I am trying to do, is to get the categories nested one by one inside the multidimensional array.

Here is the image of how I want it to be inside highlighted part:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
public function get_mixed( $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL )
{
    $this->db
        ->select('
            announcements.id,
            announcements.catid,
            announcements.uid,
            categories.title AS section,
            categories.title AS category,
            announcements.title,
            announcements.text,
            announcements.views,
            announcements.created,
            announcements.modified,
            announcements.pubdate
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'announcements.catid = categories.id', 'left')
        ->join('categories as section', 'categories.pid = section.id', 'left')
        ->order_by('created DESC, '.$this->_order_by);

    return $this->db->get( $this->_table_name, $limit, $offset )->result();
}
```

I tried first with by creating a `section` alias, but it gets me the same results.

Maybe there is a better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aliasing one of the `categories` joins as `section`, then you would need to reference any fields you want from *that* `categories` table as `section.[field]` (for example, `section.title`)

Not knowing exactly what you want, my best guess at your revised query would be:

```
$this->db
    ->select('
        announcements.id,
        announcements.catid,
        announcements.uid,
        section.title AS section,
        categories.title AS category,
        announcements.title,
        announcements.text,
        announcements.views,
        announcements.created,
        announcements.modified,
        announcements.pubdate
    ')
    ->join('categories', 'announcements.catid = categories.id', 'left')
    ->join('categories as section', 'categories.pid = section.id', 'left')
    ->order_by('created DESC, '.$this->_order_by);
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, I forgot about referencing the aliased name in SELECT. thank you